# clarification for disjoint union from any union

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

In the book "MEASURE THEORY AND FINE PROPERTIES  OF FUNCTIONS", the authors claim:
[image]
where 
[image]

> Can someone explain to me how can we use  the observation to construct the disjoint union.
>   I used $F_1=A_1\times B_2$, $F_2=A_2 \times B_2 -A_1\times B_1 $, $F_3=A_3 \times B_3 -(A_1\times B_1\cup A_2 \times B_2) $ and so one.
>
> I conclude that $(F_i)$ is a disjoint sequence of element of $(A_i\times B_i)$ which equals its union. But I don't know how to use there observation.

Comment: I guess, $F_1=A_1\times B_1$. How do you write $F_2$ as a disjoint union of sets from $P_0$?

Comment: I dont understand your remark. I think i did F2

Comment: You wrote $F_2=A_2\times B_2\,-\,A_1\times B_1$, but this is a *set difference* and not disjoint union of sets of the form $A\times B$. That's where you should use the framed identity.

Comment: But I considerd $F_3=A_3 \times B_3 -(A_1\times B_1\cup A_2 \times B_2)$ and $F_4$ and so one the all $(F_i)$ have a disjoint union. Still don't understand your remark

Comment: The problem is that $F_2\notin \mathcal P_0$, so this splitting is, though a disjoint union, but not of basic rectangles. But, $F_2, F_3,\dots$ can be split further, using the framed observation, this time to elements of $\mathcal P_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Your splitting to disjoint union in general **does not consist** of pure rectangles (elements of $\mathcal P_0$).

But, (repeatedly) using the given splitting of a *difference* of rectangles to smaller rectangles, you can further split $F_2,F_3,\dots$ so that you end up with a countable disjoint union **of rectangles**.